# Fitting a d3.js Map to a container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I currently have a d3.js map of the world using the `world-50m.json` however I am having problems fitting the entire map into a container.

Here is a picture of what the problem is:

[image]

My Code:

```
d3.json("libraries/world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
    var mapRatio = .5;
    var width = 1600;
    var height = 800;

    var svg = d3.select("div#chart svg")
                    .attr("width", "100%")
                    .attr("height", "100%")
                    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + Math.min(width, height) + " " + Math.min(width, height));

    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
                            .scale(height / Math.PI)
                            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    }

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("class", "land")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data([topojson.object(world, world.objects.land)])
          .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("class", "boundary")
        .selectAll("boundary")
        .data([topojson.object(world, world.objects.countries)])
          .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(graticule.lines)
           .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart svg").append("g");

    var serverVerticesURL = JSON_URL;
    var coordinateData = $.getJSON(
        serverVerticesURL,
        function (data, status) {
            if (status === "success") {
                // No error detected, 
                    var vertexJSON = data;
                    var coordinates = [];                   

                    // Check that we have data to map.              
                    if (vertexJSON.length > 0) {

                        // Plot points on map...                    
                        vertexJSON.forEach(function(column) 
                        {
                            var value = column.location;
                            var origin = column.vertex;
                            var col1 = "Longitude";
                            var col2 = "Latitude";
                            var atkLong = value.match(/(.*)~.*/);
                            var atkLat = value.match(/.*~(.*)/);
                            coordinates.push([atkLong[1], atkLat[1], origin]);
                        });

                        if (typeof data.message === "string") {
                            vertexJSON = [];
                        }

                        var atkNodeSelection = svg.selectAll("circle");
                        var honeypotNode = svg.selectAll("circle");

                        // Appending attack nodes
                        var atkNode = atkNodeSelection.data(coordinates)
                                            .enter().append("svg:circle")
                                                .attr("class", "atkNode")
                                                .attr("r", 5)
                                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[0]; })
                                                .attr("cy", function(d) { return projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[1]; });

                        // Appending honeypot node
                        var hpnode = honeypotNode.data([[-73.934543,41.722841]])
                                        .enter().append("svg:circle")
                                            .attr("class", "honeypot")
                                            .attr("r", 7)
                                            .attr("cx", function(d) { return projection([d[0], d[1]])[0]; })
                                            .attr("cy", function(d) { return projection([d[0], d[1]])[1]; });

                        var link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(coordinates).enter().append("line").attr("class", "link")
                            .attr("x1", function(d) { return projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[0]; })
                            .attr("y1", function(d) { return projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[1]; })
                            .attr("x2", function(d) { return projection([-73.934543,41.722841])[0]; })
                            .attr("y2", function(d) { return projection([-73.934543,41.722841])[1]; })
                            .attr("d", function (d) {
                                var x1 = projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[0],
                                    y1 = projection([parseFloat(d[0]), parseFloat(d[1])])[1],
                                    x2 = projection([-73.934543,41.722841])[0],
                                    y2 = projection([-73.934543,41.722841])[1],
                                    // Defaults for normal edge.
                                    drx = 0,
                                    dry = 0,
                                    xRotation = 0, // degrees
                                    largeArc = 0, // 1 or 0
                                    sweep = 1; // 1 or 0

                                return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + drx + "," + dry + " " + xRotation + "," + largeArc + "," + sweep + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
                            });
```

Structure of the container:

```
<div id="#chart">
     <svg>
        <g class="land | boundary | graticule">
        </g>
     </svg>
</div>
```

css:

```
/*==================================================
 * Map
 * ===============================================*/
.graticule {
    fill: #3385ff;
    fill-opacity: .3;
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

.land {
   fill: #d0d0e1;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.boundary {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #0066ff;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

/*==================================================
 * Attack Nodes
 * ===============================================*/
.atkNode {
        fill: red;
        shape-rendering: auto;
        fill-opacity: .7;
        stroke-opacity: .8;
        z-index: 2002;
}

.atkNode:hover {
    fill: #0039e6;
    fill-opacity: .5;
}
```